How to ensure reference of a smart pointer is valid in c++?
I have a metric-collecting thread that inspects worker threads to report metrics.
These worker threads can terminate at any time, so how do I ensure that when I call a worker's metrics-reporting function that worker has not been terminated?
I tried using unique_ptr, but that doesn't prevent use after free. I don't want MyMetricMonitor to own each task.
I could create shared pointer, but I want MyTask to be able to be free whenever the task is done
Is WeakPtr best here?
Example:
#include <folly/Executor.h>
#include <folly/executors/CPUThreadPoolExecutor.h>
class MyTask {
 public:
  MyTask() : {}
  void run() {
  }
};

class MyMetricMonitor {
 public:
  void addTaskToMonitor(std::unique_ptr<MyTask>& task) {
    tasks.push_back(task);
  }
  void monitor() {
    for (auto& task : tasks_) {
      task->getMetric();
    }
  }

 private:
  std::vector<MyTask> tasks;
};

int main() {
    MyMetricMonitor monitor;
    std::thread monitorThread(monitor);

    auto executor = std::make_shared<folly::CPUThreadPoolExecutor>(
      2, std::make_shared<folly::NamedThreadFactory>("Worker"));
    // Submit a task that is a class instance
    folly::via(executor.get(), [] {
        std::unique_ptr<MyTask> task = std::make_unique<MyTask>(42);
        task.run();
        monitor.addTaskToMonitor(task)
    });
    monitorThread.join();
}


NEVER pass unique pointers by reference. Since your tasks is shared between your threadpool and your monitor this is one good case where actually using a std::shared_ptr makes sense (just pass it by value). By the way next time make sure you have code that compiles task.run() will not (since task is a pointer).

@PepijnKramer I generally agree with passing unique_ptrs (or smart ones in general) by value, but I guess there’s one notable exception to this: rvalue-ref when strong exception guarantee is involved.

@PepijnKramer sorry if this is a dumb question, but how does MyTask gets clean up when the task is done if monitor continue to hold reference of MyTask if we are using shared_ptr ?
Does monitor have to check if MyTask is done and then release reference for memory of MyTask to be cleaned up?

Why not, as a thread terminates, have it remove itself from the task list (or send some message to the monitor, and tell that object to remove it)?

No not a dumb question. But it all has to do with something called "ownership" and transfering it (or not). Maybe this article will help you a bit : https://belaycpp.com/2022/03/17/who-owns-the-memory/

Far as I can tell, in your code monitor.addTaskToMonitor is called after the task has already finished execution (after task.run() returns). Moreover, task pointer would be deleted immediately after addTaskToMonitor call. There's only one chance to call getMetric - and that's instead of or within addTaskToMonitor. In light of this, it's entirely unclear what role MyMetricMonitor is even supposed to play.
